# Mutating Vuex store by v-model inside v-for loop

Tags: typescript, vuex, getter-setter, vuedraggable

I'm using vuedraggable with Vuex store, the [documentation](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) suggests each  component should have v-model attribute pointing directly at the array, so Vuex store can be mutated via setter.

The problem is: I'm dynamically adding new arrays to the store and accessing them with v-for loop in the template. Having the  tag inside v-for, I use square bracket syntax to access correct array from the list. Which gets the data rendered, but in this case v-model has no way to mutate state having no setter under "listOfArrays[index]".

I was trying to work around it by assigning the dynamic arrays directly to store properties with randomly generated names, and having an array containing list of property names, but the problem with mutating them still stays. Clearly I have wrong idea about this.

What I'm trying to achieve is: having a way to add new arrays to the $store, and later commiting mutations with component state. I would appreciate pointing in the right direction, or maybe alternative solution.

```
<template>
 <div v-for="(array, index) in listOfArrays">
  <draggable v-model="listOfArrays[index]"> ..data... </draggable>
 </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
 get listOfArrays() {
  return this.$store.getters.listOfArrays;
 }

 set listOfArrays(value) {
  this.$store.commit('updateListOfArrays', value);
 }
</script>
```